# How to add suggestion chips in webhook with actions sdk

Tags: actions-on-google, actionbuilder

I am building an action with Google **Actions SDK**, and for a scene I am using a **webhook** for `onEnter`. My question is how do I add suggestion chips using the webhook function.

This is my webhook

```js
app.handle('startSceneOnEnter',conv=>{
    conv.add('its the on enter of the scene');   
});
```

I could not find how to add suggestion chips with conversation, any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion chips can be added with the [`Suggestion`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.1.0/classes/_conversation_prompt_suggestion_.suggestion.html) class.

```js
const {Suggestion} = require('@assistant/conversation');

app.handle('startSceneOnEnter', conv => {
    conv.add('its the on enter of the scene');
    conv.add(new Suggestion({ title: 'My Suggestion' }));
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I had tried using conv.add(new Suggestion({ title: 'My Suggestion' })); but hadn't included as above.